# JYTHON 2.0 CODE -STRING MANIPULATION and replace

Tags: replace, jython, text-manipulation

> As i have already asked  this question
>   and i have later realized that tool
>   for which iam writing JYTHON CODES
>   supports presently on till 2.1 version
>   as the intepreter is of 2.1 so some of
>   the advanced technique is not working.
>
> Now being a new and excited to learn
>   more in jython so that ican write more
>   better and smarted code.
>
> 1. Is FOR LOOP faster in jython than while loop:
> 2. I have a long string taken from an XML file which looks something like
>      this
>
> CDATA[EMP_ID]]
>
> and i want this to be
>
> CDATA[TRIM(EMP_ID)]
>
> in short just add TRIM() around the
>   COLUMN NAME which keep changing ,
>
> to do the one side  I HAVE USED
>   REPLACE
>
> REPLACE ( 'CDATA[TRIM(')
>
> i searching answer for how to put the
>   close bracket irrespective any number
>   of characters after open bracket.
>
> The technique i thought if i search
>   for IF SUB (LINE,1,52 )=='CDATA[ '
>   AND THEN REPLACE ']]>' WITH 
>   ')]]>>'  solving my need.
>
> As iam trying to search with STARTWITH
>   ,SUB  its getting me other strings too
>   as they match some part of the line.
>
> In short my question
>
> 1. Is there an easy way to do it ?
> 2. If iam right , how can use the right search technique .
>
> Thanks again to all of you , this
>   forums have really helped me a lot in
>   learning jython and correcting and
>   showing me the right way.
>
> Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression might be sufficient in this case:

```
import re

f = open('your_file.xml')
try:
    xml = f.read()
    xml_with_trim = re.sub(r'(CDATA\[)([A-Z_]+)(\]\])', r'\1TRIM(\2)\3', xml)
    print xml_with_trim
finally:
    f.close()
```

The column name is matched using `'[A-Z_]+' regex` i.e., one or more capital letters or `'_'`. See documentation for the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: i dont know why but this is not working its still showing me the same result with no trim added ,i used the same code as shown above. Any other way. Thanks for your help